# Can Akka ClusterSharding actors have arguments passed in?

Tags: akka, akka-cluster

I found the same question [Akka cluster-sharding: Can Entry actors have dynamic props](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26475491/akka-cluster-sharding-can-entry-actors-have-dynamic-props), but still wonder if things have been improved during the past five years.
The question is: Is it possible to pass arguments to the actor constructor which is instantiated by Akka ClusterSharding automatically? For example, pass an actor ID to the constructor?

Comment: The new typed sharding api allows to access the entity id when creating the sharded behavior. See https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/typed/cluster-sharding.html. `  sharding.init(Entity(TypeKey)(createBehavior = entityContext => Counter(entityContext.entityId)))`. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks! Seems this is exactly what I need; the only issue is, I'm still using classic actor. I'm not quite comfortable with the typed actor, waiting for more use cases.

Comment: The only trick I've seen for this is parsing the actor path, which is icky.